# Getting ul li a title attribute with nth-child?

Tags: jquery

I have been plugging in all sorts of combination to get the the "title" attribute value via JQuery. I have googled hard and searched for the past couple of hours. My code is only able to get the "li" anchor title but cannot seem to get the other. I would appreciate it if you someone can point out what am I not doing right, please.

HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="honda">HONDA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="toyota">TOYOTA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="nissan">NISSAN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="mazda">MAZDA</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Works for the very first child

```
alert($("nav li a:nth-child(1)").attr("title"));
```

Doesn't work for other children

```
alert($("nav li a:nth-child(2)").attr("title"));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<a>` tags are only childs the [`nth-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) selector needs to be on the `li` which has siblings.

```
alert($("nav li:nth-child(2) a").attr("title"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `:nth-child` has to be on the `li`; each `a` is the first-child of its parent (the `li`). You want to find the position of each `li` relative to the `ul`.

```
alert($("nav li:nth-child(2) a").attr("title"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor change

```
alert($("nav li:nth-child(2) a").attr("title"));
```

This is because `a` is the only child so `first-child` was working. You need to place the pseudo for `li` not `a`